# Options for having two computers communicate over the internet without opening a port

Tags: web-services, email, communication, irc

What are services for allowing two computers to communicate over the internet without either of them opening a port or running a server. The two options I've identified is email (somewhat delayed) and irc, but I was wondering what other options or services were avaible.

Comment: Both irc and email involves opening ports ..

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen running irc or email servers require opening ports. I'm talking about both sides being client. I didn't need to open any ports on my router to connect to irc or send and receive emails, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is somewhat misguided. What you're asking for, essentially, is how to bypass a firewall. This is how it works: you've got two hosts, A and B:

A --- A's Firewall --- Internet --- B's Firewall --- B

When A sends a message to B, B's firewall checks if the port is open. If not, it blocks it.

A --80--> AF --80--> Internet --80--> X BF (Port 80 closed)

A's firewall works much the same:

(Port 80 Closed) AF X <--80-- Internet <--80-- BF <--80-- B

If it is open, though, B's firewall lets it through:

A ---> AF ---> Internet ---> BF ---> B

A is acting as a client here. Now, A's firewall knows there's a connection, so when B sends a message back:

A <=== AF <=== Internet <=== BF <=== B

And they can exchange messages as long as they wish, until one of them closes the connection. When that happens, A's firewall (the one without the port open) will stop allowing packets through.

So, in order to have connections that don't require changing firewall rules on either end, you can do one of the following:

1. Have a server in the middle. This is what most e-mail does - both A and B connect, as clients, to e-mail servers (whose firewalls are set up correctly to allow this). You could run your own server, or use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).
2. Find a zero day in every firewall out there.

Comment: Well, I could run why own servers, but I'm wondering what services there are to route traffic like that. I could use email, but it's slow. IRC seems like a weird solution.

Comment: I've added a link to a great service that will happily do this for you. Check it out, and if it's what you need, don't forget to accept the answer.